# I can't access my $_GET array

Tags: .htaccess, get

I think I've eaten the $_GET parameters with my .htaccess file.  Here's the .htaccess:

```
# Rewrite directory path to index.php?page=dir/dir/page
# Excludes any existing files so files can be called directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)?$ index.php?page=$1$2   [L]
```

This has been working very well. But now I need to pass some parameters to pages, and I can't figure out how to get the parameters to pass through the rewrite rule.

I'm able to see the parameters as part of the $REQUEST_URI super global, and I can process that if needed. But would like to get my .htaccess rule working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I needed to add the QSA (Query String Append) flag to the rewrite rule. The rewrite rule from above now reads:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)?$ index.php?page=$1$2   [L,QSA]
```